# Spring CRUD. Метод PATCH. Ошибка 405

Tags: java, html, spring, controller, crud

При создании html файла, для редактировании пользователя в SPRING, был выбран метод PATCH

Во время тестирования, все функции работают.
Добавление пользователей, отображение пользователей.

После обновления имени, прога возвращается на url people/id и выдает ошибку [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам HTML фаил с PATCH методом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И контроллеры :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем может быть проблема? Имеет ли смысл вместо PATCH использовать POST?
Спасибо

Comment: Если метод указан неверно на форме, то в контроллере не хватает метода который будет мапиться в форму. Из-за этого не хватает понимания ошибки 405, которая возникает в случае если метод запроса указан неверно.

Comment: Проверьте что у вас в application.properties включен spring.mvc.hiddenmethod.filter.enabled=true

Comment: Да, при добавлении **spring.mvc.hiddenmethod.filter.enabled=true** в properties, все становится на свои места. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

PATCH-метод - это HTTP-метод в то время как язык разметки HTML5 поддерживает лишь GET и POST методы. Исправление запроса на POST исправит вашу проблему, но это не соответствует принципам Best Practice для построения API.

В данном случае имеется другой выход: в вашей форме необходимо объявить поле типа «hidden», именем «_method» и значением требуемого метода. Это способ, которые обычно используется при разработке на Spring Framework с Thymeleaf.

---

### Код, который Вам необходимо вставить в вашу форму:

`<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch">`